# How to write order and limit within cakephp joins array

Tags: cakephp, join, limit

I have a join in cakephp as below:

```
$emp = $this->EmployeePersonal ->find(
          'all',
          array(
              'fields' => array('EmployeePersonal.*', 'PermanentDist.name','PresentDist.name','EmployeePosting.*','Designation.name','Department.name','Office.name' ),
              'conditions' => $condition,
              'order' => array('Designation.id'),
              'recursive' => -1,
              'joins' => array(
                          array(
                                   .................
                                   .................
                           ),

                   array(
                      'table' => 'employee_postings',
                      'alias' => 'EmployeePosting',
                      'type' => 'LEFT',
                      'order' => 'EmployeePosting.posting_from DESC',
                      'limit' => 1,
                      'conditions' => array(
                          'EmployeePosting.employee_personal_id = EmployeePersonal.id',
                      )
                  ),
              )
          )
);
```

But the lines

```
'order' => 'EmployeePosting.posting_from DESC',
'limit' => 1,
```

are not working ! That means though I was expecting to get last newest `posting_from` value, I am getting all the values ! Where I am doing wrong ? I think I have written the `order` `limit` in wrong place.

Comment: It can't be done via `find`. Use the `query` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get last newest `posting_from` you must use `'group_by' => 'employee_personal_id'` instead of `'limit' => '1'` and `'order' => 'EmployeePosting.posting_from DESC'` will remain the same in the same array.

Comment: did not get you..can you please explain

Comment: So is there any way I can select the largest `posting_from` value other than limit ?

Comment: though no multiple outputs are coming now,I am getting the result of lowest value of `EmployeePosting.posting_from` , . I have added `'order' => 'EmployeePosting.posting_from DESC',`