# Cakephp group by and order by together not working

Tags: cakephp, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to get the employees and their posting details with largest `posting_from` date.
My query is:

```
$emp = $this->EmployeePersonal ->find(
          'all',
          array(
              'fields' => array('EmployeePersonal.*', 'PermanentDist.name','PresentDist.name','EmployeePosting.*','Designation.name','Department.name','Office.name' ),
              'conditions' => $condition,
              //'order' => array('Designation.id'),
              'group' => 'EmployeePersonal.id',
              'order' => 'EmployeePosting.posting_from DESC',
                       'recursive' => -1,
              'joins' => array(

                   array(
                      'table' => 'employee_postings',
                      'alias' => 'EmployeePosting',
                      'type' => 'LEFT',

                      'conditions' => array(
                          'EmployeePosting.employee_personal_id = EmployeePersonal.id',
                      )
                  ),
              )
          )
);
```

But the above query shows the lowest `posting_from` value. Why isn't the `order` working in my case?

Comment: What query gets executed? I think you may need to describe your schema and what you're trying to do - rather than focus entirely on the query you've written and why it's wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write order and limit within cakephp joins array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23676451/how-to-write-order-and-limit-within-cakephp-joins-array). Please don't ask a new question to get clarification on the answer from your last question (???) - why did you accept the answer if it didn't solve your problem?

Comment: @AD7 your rigth, i deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

some commas and will be ready:

```
$emp = $this->EmployeePersonal ->find(
          'all',
          array(
             'joins' => array(
                   array(
                      'table' => 'employee_postings',
                      'alias' => 'EmployeePosting',
                      'type' => 'LEFT',
                      'conditions' => array(
                          'EmployeePosting.employee_personal_id = EmployeePersonal.id'
                      )
                  )
              ),
              'fields' => array('EmployeePersonal.*', 'PermanentDist.name','PresentDist.name','EmployeePosting.*','Designation.name','Department.name','Office.name'),
              'conditions' => $condition,
              //'order' => array('Designation.id'),
              'group' => 'EmployeePersonal.id',
              'order' => array(
                  'EmployeePosting.posting_from' => 'DESC'
              ),
              'recursive' => -1
        )
);
```

Comment: Its the same,I am getting the fist result(smallest posting_from) !

Comment: what are you doing in $conditions?

Comment: `But the above query shows the lowest posting_from value` - The code being run works. Since that's a parse error it's going to be a typo in this question; not the source code. (I've since corrected the question).